# Software Alternative to Flash/Animate that allows Custom Components?

Tags: flash, adobe-animate

Is there a Flash or Animate alternative that similarly allows creating custom components to be used in the IDE? I only care about static drawing output / no animation. Think: custom button with definable color and drop shadow strength, or character with parameterized hair length. Extra great would be if the software costs less than Adobe Animate. This is similar to Unity or Godot where you can create an IDE-level reusable parameterized component tool, but Unity and Godot are not drawing tools and that is what I'm looking for. Can it be done in Inkscape? Moho? Synfig?
I've been searching around for a few hours and can't find anything about this or how to do it in the open source tools I know about.
Thanks!

The closest thing I've found is maybe to create a python 'Extension' in Inkscape, and maybe with some trickery I can get it to read the current parameter values I care about, allowing multiple iterations of tweaking using the extension on the same object.

Maybe the same sort of thing can be done in Moho with `.lua` extensions. While both of the extension solutions would work, they are definitely more work than the old Flash "draw shapes, attach code, convert to reusable component" workflow.

I forgot about Microsoft's Blend was meant for this stuff, because of its integration with Visual Studio & C# and visual design products. Sadly, like Flash this tool is also extinctoware. Does Adobe really have a monopoly on this kind of tool?

I just found ReactStudio, and it is pretty much what I'm looking for.

Comment: This question is not a programming question and on top of that you pretty much forgot to explain what platform you expect the result to run on. Mobile devices? Browser? Windows desktop? AppleTV? Raspberry Pi?

Comment: It's a programming/tool question about what framework to use to get object-oriented structure with initializers, getters-setters, inheritance, and private member hiding in a context with tight coupling to SVG or similar. Designers don't understand this so I'm asking in SO. Specifying operating system has nothing to do with an answer to my question - that's premature optimization. To be clear, I'll solve the OS problem later because the framework/tool and cost is the limiting factor here.